# How to install third-party modules for ConTeXt (MacTex distribution)?

Tags: installing, context

I install MacTeX basic package and then install context by tlmgr. How do I install third-party modules?

Comment: `tlmgr` should be able to install ConTeXt packages as well. For example `tlmgr context-simplefonts` will install the simplefonts module.

Comment: Thanks it works. However could you show me how to  search for context packages only using tlmgr?

Comment: Most context packages are named `context-<modulename>`. The easiest way to search is to look at the [TeX Catalogue](ftp://ftp.u-aizu.ac.jp/pub/tex/CTAN/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#context) entry for ConTeXt or look at the [third party module](http://modules.contextgarden.net/) page on ConTeXt garden.

Answer (score 3):

In TeX Live, ConTeXt modules are names as `context-<modulename>`. You can use the TeX Live manager `tlmgr` to install any TeX Live package. So, you can install a ConTeXt module using

```
tlmgr install context-<modulename>
```